# Image is not moving to folder

Tags: php

When I clicked on the form button its successfully call the insert function and all the values stored in the variables and passed to the PHP document. The image is successfully uploaded into the database. But the image is not moving to the folder. Can any body help me to figure out this.

HTML Code

```
<form  style="border: thin solid black;">
<p>Enter Mobile Name:<input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Name" id="name"></p>
<p>Enter Mobile Price:<input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price"></p>
<p>Select The Image:<input type="file"   id="image"></p>
<p>Enter Mobile Brand:<input type="text" id="brand" placeholder="Nokia,Q mobile,Samsung,Iphone" style="width: 200px"></p>
<p>Select Category:<select id="category"> <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option> <option value="Tablet">Tablet</option></select></p>
<p><input id="b" type="button" onClick="Insert();"  value="Upload"></p>
<h5 id="message"></h5>
</form>
```

Ajax Code

```
function Insert() 
    {
        var image= document.getElementById("image").value;
        var brand= document.getElementById("brand").value;
        var price= document.getElementById("price").value;
        var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
        var category=document.getElementById("category").value;


    if (image == "" && brand == "" && name == "" && price == "" ) 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Fields";
        return;
    }
        else if (image == "" || brand == "" || name == "" || price == "" ) 
            {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Form Correctly.";
                return;
            }
        else
        { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","insertdata.php?name="+name+"&price="+price+"&image="+image+"&brand="+brand+"&category="+category,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
include("Sql_Server.php");

$error="";
$message="";
$images="";
$category="";





        $brand="".$_GET['brand']."/".basename($_GET['image']);
        $latestadded="Latest_Added/".basename($_GET['image']);
        $images=base64_encode(basename($_GET['image']));
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($latestadded,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $images."<br>";
echo $brand."<br>";
echo $_GET['image'];

    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "jfif" ) 
    {
    $message="Sorry, only jpg, jpeg, png ,jfif, gif files are allowed.";
    }   
    elseif($_GET['category']=='Mobile')
    {   

        $query="Insert Into mobiles(Image,Mobile_Name,Price,Brand)Values('".$images."','".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['price']."','".$_GET['brand']."')";

        $query2="Insert Into latest_mobiles(Image,Mobile_Name,Price,Brand)Values('".$images."','".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['price']."','".$_GET['brand']."')"; 

        $insert=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $insert2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
        if($insert && $insert2)
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_GET['image'],$brand);
        echo $message="Submitted";
        }
        else
        {
        echo $error="Not Submitted";
        }
       }
      else
        {
        $query="Insert Into tablets(Image,Tablet_Name,Price,Brand)Values('".$images."','".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['price']."','".$_GET['brand']."')";

        $query2="Insert Into latest_mobiles(Image,Mobile_Name,Price,Brand)Values('".$images."','".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['price']."','".$_GET['brand']."')"; 

        $insert=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $insert2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
        if($insert && $insert2)
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_GET['image'],$latestadded);
        copy($latestadded,$brand);  
        echo $message="Submitted";
        }
        else
        {
        echo $error="Not Submitted";
        }
        }       
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the script and the folder has at least 755 permissions?

Comment: One thing that I notice is that you missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

Comment: in your form is missing enctype='multipart/form-data' and without that, will never upload images or files in folder

Comment: But the image is upload into the database.

Comment: Also, this line is not right: `$images=base64_encode(basename($_GET['image']));` you should do this: `basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);`

Comment: without javascript code the image is uploading to the database and also moving to the folder. But with JS code its successfully passed the variables to the php document and image successfully upload into the database. But problem is that its not moving to folder.

Comment: I also tried this code $_FILES["image"]["name"] but it gives image index is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your form needs to be "multipart/form-data

Secondly you should send your file via HTTP POST not GET

Thirdly your uploaded tmp filename should be in global $_FILES 
php array. Something like this 

`$_FILES[file input name here]['tmp_name']`
This is the name under which your file is uploaded to the temporary location on the server.

Comment: I tried this but it gives 
Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xampp\htdocs\GetMobile.PK\insertdata.php on line 9

Comment: Clearly you're not sending a file but only a filename inside a query string that is later saved to the db. But since there was no file in your request then nothing is saved on the disk. If you don't trust me check the value returned from `move_uploaded_file` function call. If it's false then there was no file to begin with. Here's a link to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php